# Strange error near '' MySQL with a function

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I ask because I don't know where is the error.
I need to create a function in MySQL. I'm using PhpMyAdmin.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `aggiungiPermesso`(matricolaUtenteLoggato VARCHAR(20),nomeNuovoPermesso VARCHAR(20),descrizioneNuovoPermesso VARCHAR(250)) RETURNS VARCHAR(150)
BEGIN
DECLARE hapermesso INT;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO hapermesso FROM ottiene WHERE matricolaUtenteLoggato = ottiene.Matricola AND ID =(SELECT id FROM permesso WHERE Nome = 'Aggiungi permesso')
IF(hapermesso < 1) BEGIN
RETURN 'Errore. Non hai i permessi.';
END
INSERT INTO `permesso`(`ID`,`Nome`, `Descizione`) VALUES(0,nomeNuovoPermesso,descrizioneNuovoPermesso) RETURN 'Nuova operazione aggiunta con successo.';
END
DELIMITER;
```

The error is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

What is the error?

Comment: Where do you set the delimiter?

Comment: At last row, but I can set it at first row too... nothing change...
Where I must set the delimiter, for you?

Comment: If you do not change the delimiter **before** the function's specification to sg else, then it will remain the default ; and there comes your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because you were using wrong syntax for Return and IF. I have corrected your query and it works fine now.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `aggiungiPermesso`(matricolaUtenteLoggato VARCHAR(20),nomeNuovoPermesso VARCHAR(20),descrizioneNuovoPermesso VARCHAR(250)) RETURNS VARCHAR(150) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
DECLARE hapermesso INT;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO hapermesso FROM ottiene 
WHERE matricolaUtenteLoggato = ottiene.Matricola AND ID =(SELECT id FROM permesso WHERE Nome = 'Aggiungi permesso');
BEGIN RETURN IF(hapermesso > 1,'Errore. Non hai i permessi.','None');
END;
INSERT INTO `permesso`(`ID`,`Nome`, `Descizione`) 
VALUES(0,nomeNuovoPermesso,descrizioneNuovoPermesso); 
RETURN 'Nuova operazione aggiunta con successo.';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you. The editor give a error with all ';' but run... bah

Comment: No problem..Enjoy

Comment: Nope, the error was due to incorrect delimiter setting. The rest are just bonus.